# Graph of new species discovered per year

Tags: history

I'm looking for historical data on the number of new species described each year.

I found the [RetroSOS report](https://www.esf.edu/species/documents/sosretro.pdf) (page 3), which provides a time series for 2000–2009:

```
Year    Total number of new species described
------- -------------------------------------
2000    17,045
2001    17,003
2002    16,990
2003    17,357
2004    17,381
2005    16,424
2006    17,659
2007    18,689
2008    18,225
2009    19,232
```

This table suggests that the rate at which new species are described might be accelerating. To get a better sense of this, I'm looking for data going further back than 2000, and beyond 2009.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is **an** answer; as I'll explain, it's not getting the same numbers you quoted above (that could be a deep methodological rabbit hole), but it gives a reasonable answer.

I started from the data at [ChecklistBank](https://www.checklistbank.org/), specifically downloading [this file](https://api.checklistbank.org/dataset/9837/export.zip?format=TextTree) (warning: 45 MB) and unzipping it.

The data file contained looks like this:

```
Biota [unranked]
  Animalia [kingdom]
    Acanthocephala Rudolphi, 1802 [phylum]
      Archiacanthocephala Meyer, 1931 [class]
        Apororhynchida Thapar, 1927 [order]
          Apororhynchidae Shipley, 1899 [family]
            Apororhynchus Shipley, 1899 [genus]
              *Arhynchus Shipley, 1896 [genus]
              *Neorhynchus de Marval, 1905 [genus]
              Apororhynchus aculeatus Meyer, 1931 [species]
```

So: we extract every line with the string "[species]"; pick out the 4-digit string following a comma; and sort and count these lines. This gives us a file with a count for each 4-digit string, which *should* be the year the species was described (there's of course more complication than that, but that gets us most of the way there).  Then we can filter out obvious mistakes and count the number of described species per year in what's left.

[image]

I drew blue rectangles for the Napoleonic wars, and World Wars I & II. I started to play with breaking out species described by Linnaeus but didn't finish troubleshooting ...

I posted the results [here](http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/bolker/misc/species_year_count.csv).

The numbers for 2000-2009 don't match the ones you posted above, but I assume that's because there are a million different ways you could count new species ... however, I think my method is at least reasonable/defensible ...

```
| count | year |
|-------|------|
| 9845  | 2000 |
| 9670  | 2001 |
| 11102 | 2002 |
| 10482 | 2003 |
| 10601 | 2004 |
| 9809  | 2005 |
| 10871 | 2006 |
| 11632 | 2007 |
| 10649 | 2008 |
| 9939  | 2009 |
```

```
system("grep \\\\[species\\\\] dataset-9837.txt | \
   grep -Pv '^[[:space:]]+\\*' | \
   grep -Po '(?<=, )[0-9]{4}(?= ?\\)?\\[)' | \
  sort | uniq -c > yrs.txt")
## 1. select lines with [species]
## 2. unselect lines starting with whitespace + * (deprecated synonyms)
##  -P = perl, v = complement
## 3. grab 4-digit string after ", " and before space/paren/square bracke
##    -o = extract only matched pattern
## 4. sort and count

## attempt to get Linnaean species
system("grep 'Linnaeus, 17.*\\[species\\]' dataset-9837.txt | \
   grep -Po '(?<=, )[0-9]{4}' | sort | uniq -c > linn.txt")

library(tidyverse)
dd <- (read_table("yrs.txt", col_names = FALSE) 
    |> setNames(c("count", "year"))
    |> filter(year > 1750, year <= 2022)
)

linn <- (read_table("linn.txt", col_names = FALSE)
    |> setNames(c("count", "year"))
)

theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(dd, aes(year, count)) + geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = "gam",
                method.args = list(family = quasipoisson)) +
    scale_y_log10() +
    ## wars
    annotate(geom = "rect",
             ymin = rep(1, 3),
             ymax = rep(100000, 3),
             xmin = c(1803, 1914, 1939),
             xmax = c(1815,1919, 1946),
             alpha = 0.2,
             fill = "blue") +
    labs(y = "new species described")
ggsave("species.png")
```

Comment: Nice work. One larger problem is that plant names do not contain the year of publication, so you miss about 400k species and many more names. Synonyms would also need special attention as subsequent recombinations should not count as newly described species.

Comment: I do exclude lines starting with *, which I think (?) takes care of synonyms. Any idea where to get plant species checklists with year of description ... ?

Comment: https://powo.science.kew.org/ shows year of description, but I don't know if it can be ingested as easily as the COL data ...

Answer (score 4):

For plants IPNI provides statistics per year of newly described names: https://www.ipni.org/statistics

For Fungi and Plant the annual rate of new species has been around 2000-2500 species/year each in the past decade according to https://nph.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/ppp3.10148